# In Image Processing with Core Video(GLES and cocoa) method on iOS, how to avoid the black&white lines when i'm using a tiny picture?

Tags: image-processing, opengl-es-2.0, core-video

I'm doing Image Processing with gles2.0.
The Effects are writen as shaders.

And for acceleration on iOS, the results are drawn to textures(With frame buffer binded) which are created by **cv (core video)** functions.

All things are ok, if I use the version without cv-accerated ( OpenGL ES2.0 functions only).

But there is a problem on the cv-accerated version:
when the input-picture is very small ( such as 200*200 pixel), many unexpected lines would appear after processing with several filters.
It takes me a long time to solve this problem but it's still there.
glFinish() is called before each needed function, so this is not the point.
Thans for your help!

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUdzo.jpg)

Comment: This is a tough problem because the lines are not 100% appeared after processing with a filter. This happened after continuously processing more than 3 filters. I am thinking if my code is wrong, but the version without cv works very well.

Comment: This happened when the picture is very small. If the picture is not so small, both version work well.